# What are the equivalents of colored grep?

Tags: debugging, unix, logging, command-line, grep

Sometimes coloring a logfile or other gives a good overview when looking for *stuff* and *behaviors*

I just saw that grep have a coloring feature

```
grep -C 99999 --color <regexp> <filename>
```

What other methods are there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For searching source code, I use [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/). It's got a lot of options that make sense for searching code (such as automatically ignoring SCM directories).

Comment: DOH - that site is banned from our workplace... dont you just love Net nannies...

Comment: I'm amazed that petdance.com is banned.  Can you tell me any more about why?

Comment: For those wondering, ack is now hosted on github at https://github.com/petdance/ack

Answer (score 21):

Here is a snippet for a log coloring tool I sometimes use.

Note that is only works against stdin/stdout and in a terminal supporting ANSI colors.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define MAX_LINE 4096

#define RESET   "\033[0m"
#define BLACK   "\033[30m"      /* Black */
#define RED     "\033[31m"      /* Red */
#define GREEN   "\033[32m"      /* Green */
#define YELLOW  "\033[33m"      /* Yellow */
#define BLUE    "\033[34m"      /* Blue */
#define MAGENTA "\033[35m"      /* Magenta */
#define CYAN    "\033[36m"      /* Cyan */
#define WHITE   "\033[37m"      /* White */
#define BOLDBLACK   "\033[1m\033[30m"      /* Bold Black */
#define BOLDRED     "\033[1m\033[31m"      /* Bold Red */
#define BOLDGREEN   "\033[1m\033[32m"      /* Bold Green */
#define BOLDYELLOW  "\033[1m\033[33m"      /* Bold Yellow */
#define BOLDBLUE    "\033[1m\033[34m"      /* Bold Blue */
#define BOLDMAGENTA "\033[1m\033[35m"      /* Bold Magenta */
#define BOLDCYAN    "\033[1m\033[36m"      /* Bold Cyan */
#define BOLDWHITE   "\033[1m\033[37m"      /* Bold White */

static int selected_color = 0;
static char *colors[] = {
  "-green", GREEN,
  "-black", BLACK,
  "-red", RED,
  "-yellow", YELLOW,
  "-blue", BLUE,
  "-magenta", MAGENTA,
  "-cyan", CYAN,
  "-white", WHITE,
  "-boldgreen", BOLDGREEN,
  "-boldblack", BOLDBLACK,
  "-boldred", BOLDRED,
  "-boldyellow", BOLDYELLOW,
  "-boldblue", BOLDBLUE,
  "-boldmagenta", BOLDMAGENTA,
  "-boldcyan", BOLDCYAN,
  "-boldwhite", BOLDWHITE,
  NULL
};

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buf[MAX_LINE];
  int has_re = 0;
  regex_t re;

  if (argc > 1) {
    if (argc > 2) {
      int idx = 0;
      while (colors[idx*2]) {
        if (!strcmp(colors[idx*2], argv[1])) {
          selected_color = idx;
          break;
        }
        idx++;
      }
      if (regcomp(&re, argv[2], REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE)) {
        printf("regcomp() failed!\n");
        return -1;
      }
    } else if (regcomp(&re, argv[1], REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE)) {
      printf("regcomp() failed!\n");
      return -1;
    }
    has_re = 1;
  } else {
    printf("Usage: %s [ -red | -blue | -cyan | -white | -black | "
           "-yellow | -magenta ] <regexp>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;  
  }

  while (fgets(buf, MAX_LINE, stdin) == buf) {
    char *bbuf = buf;
    while (1) {
      if (has_re) {
        regmatch_t match[10];
        if (regexec(&re, bbuf, re.re_nsub + 1, match, 0)) {
          printf("%s", bbuf);
          break;
        } else {
          int i, idx;
          for (i=idx=0; i<1; i++) {
            if (match[0].rm_so < 0) {
              break;
            } else {
              printf("%.*s", 
                     (int)(match[i].rm_so-idx), 
                     bbuf+idx);
              printf( "%s%.*s" RESET, 
                      colors[selected_color*2+1],
                      (int)(match[i].rm_eo-match[i].rm_so), 
                      bbuf+(int)match[i].rm_so);
              idx = match[i].rm_eo;
              bbuf += idx;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }

  if (has_re) {
    regfree(&re);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many programs that support coloring like [Colortail](http://joakimandersson.se/projects/colortail/)

Maybe this can be helpful too: [GenericColouriser](http://freshmeat.net/projects/genericcolouriser/)

Answer (score 1):

We use [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/), now if they added color to their [baregrep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/index.php), that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but in case anyone is still looking, I recently created [`colorize`](https://github.com/hq6/colorize), a tool which allows one to specify either fixed patterns or regular expressions to match with specific colors. It works out of the box with an intuitive syntax for specifying highlighting, and `docopt` as its only dependency.

```
colorize.py -f 'This is an interesting line=Blue' -f 'Different topic=Red' Input.log
```