# Is there an R 3.0 compatible way to get colors in the R command line interpreter?

Tags: r, bash

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802806/is-there-a-way-to-output-some-text-to-the-r-console-in-colors) was asked a year ago, but the requirements were different (querent wanted R studio), and the solution package is not compatible with R 3.0.

I am using the R interpreter directly from the bash command line. I would like my scripts to output color text, ideally in a manner similar to how using a particular sequence of characters in C causes the color to be different.

More specifically, in C, we can output colors using printf as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961209/making-some-text-in-printf-appear-in-green-and-red). I wonder if `R 3.0.2` has a facility to do the same.

Comment: The example you provided uses ANSI escape sequences to show colors. Those are interpreted by your terminal so e.g. cat("\033[32;1m OK \033[0m\n") in R will work.

Comment: Touche. I tried with `print` and it just gave me the characters back. If you write your commend as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI sequences in the question you mentioned are processed by the terminal emulator so they will work fine in R:

```
cat("\033[32;1m OK \033[0m\n")
```

Note that `\033` is (octal) code for `escape` symbol. It is **one** (non-printable) symbol which tells the terminal to start interpreting the control sequence. `print` when given `\033` will output the  four symbols `\`, `0`, `3`, `3` literally which, of course, tells the terminal nothing. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for the full list of ANSI escape sequences.