# Python: printing in color and with style

Tags: python, printing, stdout, ansi-colors

If I want to print colored text, I would just do, using codes

```
green = '\033[0;32m'
print green + 'Hello'
```

and that gives me green text. If I want to have bold text, I would just use the code for bold, which is `'\033[1m'`

Now, I tried to combine them as

```
print bold + green + 'Hello'
```

where `bold` is the aforementioned code, and that didn't work, gave me just green text with no bold style.

Anyway, what am I missing to combine color with style?

Comment: Is bold, without any color, working?

Comment: This is a question about how to combine ANSI codes, not about Python code, really.

Comment: And they will be different depending on the terminal type.

Comment: BOLDGREEN='\033[1m\033[32m'
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961209/making-some-text-in-printf-appear-in-green-and-red)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommand [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dnmellen/5584007) by Diego Navarro Mellén.

You can combine whatever you like when doing something like this:

```
with pretty_output(BOLD, FG_GREEN) as out:
    out.write('This is a bold text in green')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Or Duan's answer, turns out that the code I'm using for green works well alone but somehow when concatenated with another code does prevent the combination of styles.

In the reported Gist, the code for green text is

```
green = '\033[32m'
```

so lacks the 0; I have in mine. With this code, the concatenation achieves the result.

It's because the 0 in front is resetting, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).