# jshint output looks wrong in file but right in console

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I ran jshint on a very simple file that looks like

```
if ( 1 == 2 ) {
}
```

And the output is kind of weird looking. I have the text being output to a logfile, and this is what the log looks like

```
^[[4mRunning "lint:files" (lint) task^[[24m
Linting src/bad.js...^[[31mERROR^[[39m
^[[31m[^[[39m^[[33mL1^[[39m^[[31m:^[[39m^[[33mC8^[[39m^[[31m]^[[39m ^[[33mExpected '===' and instead saw '=='.^[[39m
if ( 1 ^[[31m^[[7m=^[[27m^[[39m= 2 ) {
```

But if I print it to the console it looks like

```
Linting src/bad.js...ERROR
[L1:C8] Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
if ( 1 == 2 ) {
```

Any thoughts why the file version is odd looking like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are console color commands.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal) as reference

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is there a way to exclude the color? Jenkins console doesn't seem to display it.

Comment: Depends, which tool are you using to run jshint?

Comment: Sorry i'm not too familiar with grunt. The default jshint package in npm doesn't produce colored output though, so maybe its just a matter of specifying the right reporter.

Answer (score 2):

Grunt has the `--no-color` option to remove coloring, so:

```
grunt --no-color myJSHintTask
```

will output without ANSI colored codes ;)

[**Here**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/510) for more infos