# Colored boost::log shows shifted colors

Tags: c++, boost

I need to add coloring to boost log on Windows. Very simple - if error - use red ink, if warning - yellow ink, otherwise - white. No point to quote my code. I used exactly this solution (2nd answer, I suppose 1st answer is for Linux only):

[How to add color coding to boost::log console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309479/how-to-add-color-coding-to-boostlog-console-output)

I found few others, but all are based on the same principle - set console foreground color, using win32 api and do that in a sink. Problem is that it's not good. If log is receiving messages from multiple sources, sometimes color is applied to a fragment (not even a full) line and often another line (previous or next). I declared sink as synchronous (with asynchronous, coloring looked like a drawing of a mad man). Is there any way to stabilize / fix that?

Voitek

Comment: Are you logging from a single thread? Seems like you have synchronization issue and colors being wrong is just a side effect.

Comment: No. From many threads. Each thread live it's own life. But the log is one. For the entire application. Is boost::log not thread-safe? I was sure it can queue messages from multiple threads...

Answer (score 0):

Even though your logging function is thread-safe, using it might still require synchronisation.

Consider two threads, each doing one of the below:

1. `strm << red << "message";`
2. `strm << white << "other message";`

The scheduler might schedule

- thread 1 does `strm << red`
- thread 2 does `strm << white`
- thread 1 does `strm << "message"`
- thread 2 does `strm << "other message"`

You get "message" followed by "other message", both in white. This is still considered thread-safe and OK.

One first option is to concatenate the message, colored, in a single string and provide it to your logging API:

`strm << red + "message";`. You'll need to fix this line so that `red` is a std:string or something that can be concatenated with `"message"`. But the important part is that the loggin API gets a single call with color and content in a single go.

A second option is to put a single mutex around each logging block where you submit colors and text.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing from this answer is usable. I can't add some special characters in Windows to color the text. coloring is available only through win32 api. As for the second suggestion - the mutex - this is not working as well. Problem here is that stream is not flushed inside a sink function. It's flushed outside of it.

Comment: Then lock a mutex before the first `SetConsoleTextAttribute` and unlock it after the std::cout and second `SetConsoleTextAttribute`.