# Configure Boost.Log v2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm using Boost.Log V2 1.75.0 and setting up my environment from configuration file by using `boost::log::init_from_stream(config);`

Is it possible to declare colored console sink trough configuration file or is there any way add colored output to the console?

Now, I add as many Console sink as many log level available in Boost Trivial Logger and filter them by distinct level, but I don't think, that this is the right way. Example:

```
[Sinks.ConsoleSinkTrace]
Destination=Console
Filter="%Severity% = trace"
Format="\033[0;35m[%TimeStamp%] [%ProcessId%] [%ThreadId%] [%Severity%] - %Message%\033[0m"
Asynchronous=false
AutoFlush=true

[Sinks.ConsoleSinkDebug]
Destination=Console
Filter="%Severity% = debug"
Format="\033[0;34m[%TimeStamp%] [%ProcessId%] [%ThreadId%] [%Severity%] - %Message%\033[0m"
Asynchronous=false
AutoFlush=true
```

... and so on...

**Update**

I have found the SO post suggested by @AndreySemashev, but I don't really understand, how can I accommodate it into my project:
My key expectation is that I want to configure Boost.Log via file, so:

1. if I delete console sink from config file at all, how to set the formatter to the sink? (I guess `sink` is a Console type sink that won't be instantiated if there is no such section in the config file)

> sink->set_formatter(&coloring_formatter);

2. if I provide a new formatter method, I assume, that handling the entire format string given in the config file is my responsible. I would like to avoid this too

Are these observations correct, or do I miss something?

Thank you

Comment: You should ask one question per SO question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add color coding to boost::log console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309479/how-to-add-color-coding-to-boostlog-console-output)

Comment: Hi @AndreySemashev, thank you for your comments. I will split my post into three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a formatter with coloring support is described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38316911/4636534), here I will focus on how to incorporate that formatter into a settings file.

Boost.Log supports extending its settings file parser by [registering sink factories](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.sinks), which you can leverage in your case. Since you can reuse the [`text_ostream_backend`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_ostream) for output, you don't have to implement a new sink, but you do need to customize its configuration.

```
class colored_console_factory :
    public logging::sink_factory< char >
{
public:
    // Creates the sink with the provided parameters
    boost::shared_ptr< sinks::sink > create_sink(settings_section const& settings)
    {
        typedef sinks::text_ostream_backend backend_t;
        auto backend = boost::make_shared< backend_t >();

        backend->add_stream(
            boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream >(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter()));

        // Read settings and configure the backend accordingly
        if (auto auto_flush = settings["AutoFlush"])
            backend->auto_flush(*auto_flush == "1" || *auto_flush == "true");

        auto sink =
            boost::make_shared< sinks::synchronous_sink< backend_t > >(backend);

        // You can reuse filter and formatter parsers provided by Boost.Log
        if (auto filter = settings["Filter"])
            sink->set_filter(logging::parse_filter(*filter));

        if (auto format = settings["Format"])
        {
            logging::formatter fmt = logging::parse_formatter(*format);
            // Wrap the parsed formatter with coloring
            sink->set_formatter(coloring_formatter(std::move(fmt)));
        }

        return sink;
    }
};
```

In the above, `coloring_formatter` is a function object that wraps the parsed formatter with coloring prefix and suffix in the output. The function object must have the standard signature of the formatter.

```
class coloring_formatter
{
public:
    typedef void result_type;
    typedef basic_formatting_ostream< char > stream_type;

public:
    explicit coloring_formatter(logging::formatter&& fmt) :
        m_fmt(std::move(fmt))
    {}

    result_type operator() (
        logging::record_view const& rec, stream_type& strm) const
    {
        // Output coloring prefix
        auto severity = rec[logging::trivial::severity];
        if (severity)
        {
            switch (severity.get())
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        // Let the wrapped formatter produce its output
        m_fmt(rec, strm);

        // Output coloring suffix
        if (severity)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

private:
    logging::formatter m_fmt;
};
```

Refer to the answer I mentioned earlier for details on `coloring_formatter` implementation.

Comment: Thank you @AndreySemashev. I think, adding this sink support to the library would be a welcome.