# How to change colors of Bash in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ls

[image]

I'm working in an [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). I can barely read the dark blue print in Bash in the screenshot. How can I modify the colours in Bash?

Comment: color options should be configurable in your terminal settings

Comment: Check this out, might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console/466203#466203

Comment: This is not a `bash` issue; it's a combination of what color codes the `ls` program can output and how your particular terminal interprets them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How do I output coloured text to a Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change colors in terminal settings, use
menu *Terminal* → *Preferences* → *Profiles* → <kbd>Edit</kbd> → tab *Colors*

Command line:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
# Insert at the end. This will make your directory's red
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;31:' ; export LS_COLORS
# Save file
# Restart terminal
```

Comment: Thank you, thats a big help!

Comment: In [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) it is menu *Edit* → *Profile Preferences* → tab *Colors*