# how can i make use of dirent.h file to print the files in a directory?

Tags: c, filesystems

I need to print .c files, executables, and directories in seperate color. Please suggest me some ideas. Thanks in advance

```
int main(void)
{

        DIR *d;
        int iNum = 0;
        struct dirent *dir;
        char *ptr = ".";
        char *ptr1 = "..";

        d = opendir(".");

        if (d)
        {

                while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
                {
                        if(strcmp(ptr,dir->d_name) && strcmp(ptr1,dir->d_name))
                        {
                                printf("%d\n", dir->d_type);
                                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                                iNum++;
                        }
                }
                closedir(d);
        }
        printf("the number of files are %d\n",iNum);

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: pls tell me hoe to use header files efficiently

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Does it compile? Does it work as expected or not? BTW: don't use names such as "ptr" or "ptr1", why don't you call them for example "dot" and "twodots" ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

You just need to include the required header files.

```
#include <dirent.h>   // for opendir etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // for printf
```

The rest of the program is a good start and looks more or less correct to me.

For using colors please look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal).

Comment: Wow, some gutless wonder downvoted without a comment.  For what?  Answering the question?  Amazing how many people forget what it's like to try writing C without even knowing where to begin looking for answers.