# Highlighting the particular word when printing the line

Tags: c++, printing, colors, output

I have a program which allows the user to input a word they want to search for in the given large text file. The program separates the books inside the text files and counts the number of occurrence of user-input word in each book. After that, user can choose the book so that the program  print all the lines in the book which contains the user's word. I was wondering if their is any technique to highlight the search word whenever we print out all the matching line. I am very new to C++ and any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may need a library to do this. standard `c++` has no concept of colors or highlighting text.

Comment: How are you running your code? And what operating system are you using? If you're on Linux in a terminal, you can use [ANSI color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616912/2602718).

Comment: I am writing on online compiler

Comment: @lyatit Did you try the ANSI color codes that schhe001 gave you a link to? If the online compiler supports color output, I'd start testing with those. (darn - undid my upvote to schhe001's comment - didn't mean to).

Comment: Highlighting depends on the console or terminal that is receiving the output.  There are many methods for highlighting, if the console or terminal supports highlighting.

Comment: Since you're apparently showing text on a web site, I'd probably use markdown. Markdown is easy to generate, and easy to find code to render it on a web site as well.