# Print colorful ascii art in CPP console

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, console, ascii-art

I created ASCII art with npm cfonts and I want to print it in cpp with `std::cout` but it won't display anything.

How it should be displayed:

[image]

This is my ascii art:

```
\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m╗\033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m╗\033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m╗\033[39m\033[34m \033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m╗\033[39m\033[94m \033[39m
 \033[91m╚\033[39m\033[91m═\033[39m\033[91m═\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m╔\033[39m\033[91m═\033[39m\033[91m═\033[39m\033[91m╝\033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m╔\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m╝\033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m╔\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m╝\033[39m\033[34m \033[39m\033[94m╚\033[39m\033[94m═\033[39m\033[94m═\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m╔\033[39m\033[94m═\033[39m\033[94m═\033[39m\033[94m╝\033[39m\033[94m \033[39m
 \033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m║\033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m╗\033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m╗\033[39m\033[34m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m║\033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m
 \033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m║\033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m╔\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m╝\033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[34m╚\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m║\033[39m\033[34m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m║\033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m
 \033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m█\033[39m\033[91m║\033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m█\033[39m\033[31m╗\033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m█\033[39m\033[34m║\033[39m\033[34m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m█\033[39m\033[94m║\033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m
 \033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m╚\033[39m\033[91m═\033[39m\033[91m╝\033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[91m \033[39m\033[31m╚\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m═\033[39m\033[31m╝\033[39m\033[31m \033[39m\033[34m╚\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m═\033[39m\033[34m╝\033[39m\033[34m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m╚\033[39m\033[94m═\033[39m\033[94m╝\033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m\033[94m \033[39m
```

Comment: That depends on whether your terminal is able to interprete the terminal commands you used.

Comment: FYI: [SO: How do I output coloured text to a Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616912/7478597)

Comment: Btw. to demonstrate your issue, a shorter sequence would've done as well. ;-) (Though, I  like the result of your test.)

Comment: Encoding could be an issue as well. (Is your source code stored as UTF-8? Is your console set to UTF-8?)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I want to display it in a windows console application

Comment: Concerning the Windows console, I'm quite sure that it's limited to 16 colors (or so).

Comment: FYI: [SO: How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755142/7478597)